# REGEX.. convert X_FOO_BAR to fooBar

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a java DAO class that will read a table's metadata and convert the column names.  I'm having trouble with the REGEX for the conversion based on the following rules..

```
- remove first 2 characters
- convert all letters to lowercase with the exception of the first character after the underscore (_) symbol
- remove underscore
```

so...

```
X_H -> h
X_THE_FIND -> theFind
Y_SCORE_CARD -> scoreCard
Y_PARTNER -> partner
```

(note: the database columns only contain uppercase letters and may contain one or more underscore characters.  The first 2 characters will always either be X_ or Y_.  The column will name will always have at least 3 characters.)

Comment: Too bad it isn’t Perl, where the solution is simply `lcfirst(join("", map { ucfirst lc } split(/_/, substr($string, 2))))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [WordUtils in the Apache Commons lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html) it can be done in 1 line:

```
// assuming str is your String
str = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str.substring(2), new char[]{'_'}).replace("_", "");
```

Comment: I didn't use this solution but I selected your answer because I learned something new!

Comment: Thanks for selecting it. I also learnt about this library few months back only.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need regexes. I'll get you started and you can finish.

```
String input = Y_SCORE_CARD;
String tokens = input.substring(2).split("_");
String output = // lowercase characters for each token except first and join together
```

Comment: split, of course!  I was trying so hard to get it working with REGEX that the obvious didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regular expressions wizard, but it seems to me that this would be simpler without any regex at all. Just try something like this:

```
public static String convert(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.toLowerCase().split("_");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < parts.length; i++) {
        builder.append(Character.toUpperCase(s[i].charAt(0)));
        builder.append(s[i].substring(1));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```